# Python set() constructor

Tags: python, set

How to modify the Set() constructor to accept an optional variable argument to which a collection of initial values can be passed to initialize the set? The prototype for the new constructor should look as follows:

```
def Set( self, *initElements = None )
```

It can then be used as shown here to create a set initialized with the given values:

```
s = Set( 150, 75, 23, 86, 49 )
```

Comment: What is wrong with `set([150, 75, 23, 86, 49])`?

Comment: Do you actually want to *modify* it, or do you want to make a new one? If it's the first, good luck. If it's the second, write it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

You can either use a list of numbers to initialize a set, like this

```
set([150, 75, 23, 86, 49])
```

Or you can use set literal notation, like this

```
{150, 75, 23, 86, 49}
```

The advantage of the `set` constructor is that, we can use any iterator which has hashble items in it.

Answer (score 1):

It already does, you just need more brackets.

```
set([150, 75, 23, 86, 49])
```